# How to get Textarea InnerHTML in Code Behind ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using [jQuery Text Editor](http://jqueryte.com/), which renders a `TextArea` tag. 
I am using `runat="server"`.

But when i am trying to access it through Code behind like `txtArea1.Value`,
 i am getting blank string (""). Is there any way to get `HTML` (value) of the editor (`textArea`) through Code behind?

Comment: What is the content of `Request.Form` on postback?

Comment: It should be `txtArea1.Text` if you have `runat="server"`

Comment: Some code would make help easier

Answer (score 0):

Html code is located in dynamically created iframe (innerHTML).

Try to use: 
el=document.getElementById('id_name_editor');
remBr=el.innerHTML.split(/
/); 
alert(remBr);

//I Checked. It's work in TINY Editor =)